# Block RewriteRule in robots.txt

Tags: apache, robots.txt

Here is an example RewriteRule from my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^ABC$ index.php?partner_id=123&utm_source=partner&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=ABC [L]
```

So `http://mywebsite.com/123` would point to `index.php?partner_id=123&utm_source=partner&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=ABC`

Index.php file is a very important page to be properly indexed by search engines, but I would like to block `http://mywebsite.com/123` from being indexed without affecting `http://mywebsite.com/` or `http://mywebsite.com/index.php` from being indexed.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to block `http://mywebsite.com/123`, but allow `http://mywebsite.com/123index.php`, then you need an `Allow` and a `Disallow`:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /123index.php
Disallow: /123
```

This will disallow anything that starts with `/123`, but specifically allow `/123index.php`.

Standard robots.txt syntax doesn't let you disallow specific URLs. Rather, it disallows URLs that start with the pattern that you specify.

Google and Bing (and some others) have some extensions to the standard syntax. Using Google's `$` wildcard support, you could write:

```
Disallow: /123$
```

And that would block just that one URL. Other crawlers might or might not support that syntax.

Note in response to comment:

If I understand correctly, after your comment, you want to allow `http://mywebsite.com/index.php`, but block `http://mywebsite.com/123`. If you know there are no other resources that start with `/123`, then you can write:

```
Disallow: /123
```

That will block anything that starts with `/123`. For example, `/123/file.html` and `/123abc`. If there *are* other resources that start with `/123` and you want to allow them, then you'll need:

```
Disallow: /123$
```

But understand that Google and *maybe* Bing will respect that wildcard. Many other crawlers won't.

Comment: Sorry should have been http://mywebsite.com/index.php not http://mywebsite.com/123index.php